# If the scattering amplitudes are Lorentz scalars, why is S-matrix Lorentz covariant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, hilbert-space, covariance, s-matrix-theory

All observers should agree on the probabilities: $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{R}_1 \rightarrow \mathcal{R}_2)$ in an inertial frame $\mathcal{O}$  = $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{R}_1' \rightarrow \mathcal{R}_2')$ in another inertial frame $\mathcal{O'}$, where $\mathcal{R}$ is any ray in Hilbert space. They are Lorentz scalars. But S-matrix, which is just an array of transition amplitudes, is actually Lorentz covariant and is given by:
\begin{equation}
S_{p_1', \sigma_1', n_1';p_2', \sigma_2', n_2'; ... } =  e^{i a_\mu {\Lambda^\mu} _\nu(p_1'^\nu+  p_2'^\nu + ..  - p_1^\nu -  p_2^\nu ... )} \times \sqrt{\frac{(\Lambda p_1)^0}{p_1^0}} \sqrt{\frac{(\Lambda p_2)^0}{p_2^0}}...\\
              \sqrt{\frac{(\Lambda p_1')^0}{p_1'^0}} \sqrt{\frac{(\Lambda p_2')^0}{p_2'^0}}...
        \times \sum_{\bar{\sigma}_1', \bar{\sigma}_2', ...} \mathcal{D}^{(j_1')*}_{\bar{\sigma}_1' \sigma_1'}(W(\Lambda, p_1')) \mathcal{D}^{(j_2')*}_{\bar{\sigma}_2' \sigma_2'}(W(\Lambda, p_2')) ...\\
        \times \sum_{\bar{\sigma}_1, \bar{\sigma}_2, ...} \mathcal{D}^{(j_1)}_{\bar{\sigma}_1 \sigma_1}(W(\Lambda, p_1)) \mathcal{D}^{(j_2')}_{\bar{\sigma}_2 \sigma_2}(W(\Lambda, p_2)) ... \times S_{\Lambda p_1, \bar{\sigma_1}', n_1'; \Lambda p_2, \bar{\sigma_2}', n_2'; .....}
\end{equation}
Why? If S-matrix is Lorentz covariant, it would mean that the transition amplitude measured by different observers are different. But then how are transition probabilities are the same?

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly but don't initial and final states also transform under a Lorentz transformation such that the amplitude is indeed a Lorentz scalar?

Comment: I agree, I would think that it is a Lorentz scalar, but I find statements in Weinberg even saying that "Lorentz transformation of S-matrix is complicated by the momentum dependent matrices associated with each particle's spin" or S-matrix covariance, so I am confused. I can only see that if we ignore the scrambling of spin indices and just right S matrix in another frame as $S_{\Lambda p_1, \bar{\sigma_1}', n_1'; \Lambda p_2, \bar{\sigma_2}', n_2'; .....}$, then there is some transformation property of S-matrix. But other inertial observer doesn't really observe this transformed S-matrix.

Comment: This discussion is in Weinberg Chapter 3 under Symmetries of S-matrix, if you would like to read more about it.